# Google Analytics change page URI in pages report

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have a page of my website pulling in to the pages report as "/configurator" when that text is nowhere in the page's URI. I'm told it (along with a few other pages) are set up as a separate "component" on the website- all pulling in as "/configurator".

I'm hoping someone can provide a solution in which I can change how this page pulls into the report, in essence, changing the URI.

Here is the current URI. I would like to change it to show up as "/confirm"
/schedule/0e81a5a5-90c9-431b-e9c9-08d6129095f1/confirm

Thank you much!
Sarah

Comment: Welcome to [so].Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Use `code blocking` for code and log and error texts and **bold** and *italics* to highlight things

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is showing up as "configurator" is probably because it is a single page application. The different URIs you're seeing is because the app is doing the page routing.

Depending on how Google Analytics is implemented, you would have different solutions.

**If GA is implemented using analytics.js**
If you look at the tracking code provided by Google for analytics.js, you'll see there's the line: "ga('send', 'pageview');" this line sends the current URI(amongst other data) to GA on page load. If this how GA is implemented in your SPA, it will capture the URI before the SAP gets a chance to change the URI.

To fix this, you'll need to use the "send" command manually whenever the SAP routs to a new screen, see here for reference: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages

**If GA is implemented using GTM**
Similar thing with analytics.js, the GA tag is being triggered on pageview, which is the loading of the app. For this, you'll need to modify the trigger to a specific "routing" event that the SPA will need to fire and configure GTM to look for that trigger. You will also need to overwrite the "page" parameter using the "Fields to set" portion of the tag if you want to change the URI. There are other parameters that you can overwrite as well.